# How can I add a $key=>$value pair to an associative array using a foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative

I have two associative arrays I wish to combine with a foreach loop:

```
$arr1 = array( 'wikipedia.org' => 11, 'bing.com' => 9, 'google.com' => 8, 'blekko.com' => 7, 'groove.com' => 6, 'blo.com' => 5, 'ekko.com' => 4, 'rokko.com' => 3, 'always.com' => 2, 'popo.com' => 1);
$arr2 = array( 'google.com' => 20, 'blekko.com' => 19, 'wikipedia.org' => 8, 'bing.com' => 7, 'blo.com' => 6, 'ekko.com' => 5, 'groove.com' => 4, 'popo.com' => 3, 'always.com' => 2, 'rokko.com' => 1);
```

I use a new array

```
$combined = $arr1;
```

with a foreach loop

```
foreach($arr2 as $key=>$value)
{
    array_push($combined,$value); 
}
```

... which adds the value but not the key. I think I know why, but cannot find a way to add the key and the value. This works for a single line, but frustratingly nor in a foreach loop!

```
$combined=array_merge(array('blovk.com'=>'44'),$combined);
```

Comment: What do you want to do with duplicate keys?

Comment: `$arr1[$key] = $value` is all you'd need inside the loop...

Answer (score 5):

`$aggregatedResults[$key] = $value;`

It should be that simple...

Comment: Unfortunately that just replaces the values but does not add the new data to the end of the associative array! you can try it yourself. By the way I just replaced the variable $aggregatedResults for $combined, if anybody is wondering.

Comment: What do you mean by "push back"?

Comment: I just amended the comment Jessica to a better phrasing.

Comment: @user2320251 You cannot add an entry with a key that already exists to the end of your array; array keys are unique.

Comment: It can't add it to the end if it already exists - what is your end goal?

Comment: Thanks a million to Jeroen and Jessica, that advice helped me out. Problem solved. :-)